# Find all roots of a nonlinear function

Tags: python, numerical-methods, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

Let us assume I have a smooth, nonlinear function f: R^n -> R with the (known) maximum number of roots N. How can I find the roots efficiently? Right now I have calculated the function on the grid on a preselected area, refined the grid where the function is below a predefined threshold and continued that routine, but this does not seem to be very efficient, though, because I have noticed that it is difficult to select the area correctly before and to define the threshold accordingly.

Comment: Try it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to go about this of course, scipy is known to contain the safest and most efficient method for finding a single root provided you know the interval:
[scipy.optimize.brentq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq)

to find more roots using some estimate you can use:
[scipy.optimize.fsolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve)

de Moivre's formulae to use for root finding that is fairly quick in comparison to others (in case you would rather build your own method):
given a complex number  [image]

the n roots are given by:

[image]

where k varies over the integer values from 0 to n − 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can square the function and use global optimization software to locate all the minima inside a domain and pick those with a zero value.
Stochastic multistart based global optimization methods with clustering are quite proper for this task.